# Convert month(datetime) to int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert `month(datetime)` to `int` in SQL Server.

Something like

```
select convert(varchar, month(getdate())
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

From  [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187813.aspx) `MONTH (Transact-SQL)`

> Returns an integer that represents the month of the specified date.

So you don't have convert to integer

Comment: @AngelosDimoglis consider accepting this as the correct answer so that others with the same question may find it!

Answer (score 1):

`MONTH()` function return `INT` type. Then, you just use this:

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether you are really only interested in the month of the date, or also the year. When sorting do you want this January to come before last December, or after it?
In case you want to keep chronological order you might also want to use `YEAR(datetime)` in addition to `MONTH(datetime)`.